# Measuring inflow and outflow traffic with Jetty based app

Tags: jetty

My server application is using embedded jetty as an http end point. It hosts several web applications with a bunch of jsp/servlets as well as several web services.

This application will eventually be deployed on the cloud but before that I'd like to make sure that this app measures the inflow and outflow (in bytes) coming through the jetty. I could probably make a global filter and count bytes somehow..

But is there a more **intelligent** way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check for [`NetworkTrafficListener`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/io/NetworkTrafficListener.html) in Jetty 7 & 8, and how to use it in [this test class](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-server/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/NetworkTrafficListenerTest.java?h=jetty-8).